# How to do a circular (sub)sort of sets in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, circular-list

Consider the following minimized example:

**Code:**

```
a = [(1,'A'), (2,'A'), (3,'A'), (4,'A'), (5,'A')]
b = [(1,'B'), (2,'B'), (3,'B')]
c = []
d = [(1,'D'), (2,'D'), (3,'D'), (4,'D')]

print(sorted(a+b+c+d))
```

**Result:**

```
[(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'D'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (2, 'D'), (3, 'A'), (3, 'B'), (3, 'D'), (4, 'A'), (4, 'D'), (5, 'A')]
```

Python sorts the list of sets by the first item of each set and then by the second. That's fine.
Now, I need the second sort order to be "circular" in strings (not sure if this is the right term for it).
Furthermore, I want to specify the last string in the new ordered list. For example if I specify `'B'`, the ordered list should start from `'C'`. If `'C'` doesn't exist it should start from `'D'`, etc. However, it could also happen that the specified character might not be in the list, e.g. if `'C'` doesn't exist the new sorted list should nevertheless start from `'D'`.

***Edit:***

Sorry, I didn't add the desired output order of the list of sets to make it clear.
Assuming I would specify `mySpecialSort(myList,'B')`.
Then there should be first all the sets containing `1`'s as highest priority sort order and then the "circular" strings (here starting from `'D'`, since there is no `C` in the list).

*Desired sort order:*

```
[(1, 'D'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'D'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'D'), (3, 'A'), (3, 'B'), (4, 'D'), (4, 'A'), (5, 'A')]
```

or in shortened readable form:
`1D, 1A, 1B, 2D, 2A, 2B, 3D, 3A, 3B, 4D, 4A, 5A`

A (cumbersome) solution I came up (however so far ***only***) for the "circular" sort on a single character list (here with duplicates) would be the following:

**Code:**

```
myList = ['A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'Z', 'A', 'J', 'K', 'T']

def myCircularSort(myList,myLast):
    myListTmp = sorted(list(set(myList + [myLast])))                     # add myLast, remove duplicates and sort
    idx = myListTmp.index(myLast)                                        # get index of myLast
    myStart = myListTmp[(idx+1)%len(myListTmp)]                          # get the start list item
    
    myListSorted = sorted(list(set(myList)))                             # sorted original list
    print("Normal sort:                  {}".format(myListSorted))
    idx_start = myListSorted.index(myStart)                              # find start item and get its index
    myNewSort = myListSorted[idx_start:] + myListSorted[0:idx_start]     # split list and put in new order
    print("Circular sort with {} as last: {}\n".format(myLast,myNewSort))

myCircularSort(myList,'D')
myCircularSort(myList,'X')
```

**Result:**

```
Normal sort:                  ['A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'T', 'Z']
Circular sort with D as last: ['E', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'T', 'Z', 'A', 'D']

Normal sort:                  ['A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'T', 'Z']
Circular sort with X as last: ['Z', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'T']    # X actually not in the list
```

However, now I am stuck on how to get this "circular" sort (on the second item of the list of sets) together with the "normal" sort (on the first item of the list of sets).

Alternatively, I could possibly think of a "brute force" method to find the highest index (here: `4`) and all existing strings (here: `A`-`Z`) and check the existence of each combination in two nested for-loops.
Am I on the right track or would I do something horribly complicated and inefficient or am I missing some smart Python features?

**Edit2:**

After some further search, I guess `lambda` and `cmp(x,y)` would have done the job (see an [example](http://%20https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch02s05.html)), but it doesn't seem to exist in Python3 anymore. So, then probably maybe something with `operator.itemgetter()` or `operator.methodcaller()` from which I still don't have a clue how to use since I'm missing good examples...

Comment: what about `sorted(l, key=lambda x: ord(x)-(ord('D')+1) if ord(x)-(ord('D')+1) >=0 else ord('Z') + (ord(x)-(ord('D')+1)))` for `Circular sort with D as last`

Comment: `sorted(l, key=lambda x: ord(x)-(ord('X')+1) if ord(x)-(ord('X')+1) >=0 else ord('Z') + (ord(x)-(ord('X')+1)))` for the second one

Comment: result `['A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'T', 'Z']` and `['Z', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'T']`

Comment: @Epsi95 thank you for your suggestion, but I needed more than a circular sort of characters. I guess I found a solution, see my answer.

Comment: Is your input like standalone lists `a`, `b`, `c`, etc or directly `a+b+c+..`?

Comment: @iGian starting point is several separate lists, but I guess for sorting I have to merge them anyhow, right or is there maybe a simpler solution with separate lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict to map a letter to its correct position:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as ABC

start = ABC.index('D') + 1

sorter = {
    ABC[(n + start) % len(ABC)]: n
    for n in range(len(ABC))
}

myList = ['A', 'D', 'E', 'G', 'Z', 'A', 'J', 'K', 'T']

print(sorted(myList, key=sorter.get))

# ['E', 'G', 'J', 'K', 'T', 'Z', 'A', 'A', 'D']
```

To work with arbitrary keywords, extract them into a `keys` list, rearrange it as desired and use `keys.index(word)` as a sort key:

```
myList = [
    (1, 'ARTHUR'),
    (2, 'CHARLIE'),
    (3, 'GEORGE'),
    (4, 'HARRY'),
    (5, 'JACK'),
    (6, 'LEO'),
    (7, 'MUHAMMAD'),
    (8, 'NOAH'),
    (9, 'OLIVER'),
]


def circ_sorted(lst, start):
    keys = sorted(e[1] for e in lst)
    less = sum(1 for k in keys if k <= start)
    keys = keys[less:] + keys[:less]
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda e: (keys.index(e[1]), e[0]))

print(circ_sorted(myList, 'LEO')) ## [MUHAMMAD, NOAH...]
print(circ_sorted(myList, 'IAN')) ## [JACK, LEO...]
```

Comment: thank you! That would shorten my cumbersome circular sort. Now, I need to figure out how to do this with strings and together with the list of sets.

Comment: argh... I spent so much time on finding my solution and now you're "ruining" it with your short and elegant solution ;-). I tested your suggestion with my data and if I swap to `(e[0],keys.index(e[1]))`  it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Phew, this was pretty time consuming, but I guess I have a solution now. At least the result seems to have the desired order.
The module `functools` offers `cmp_to_key` to replace `cmp()` which apparently was removed in Python3. At least that's what I found [here](https://py.checkio.org/blog/how-did-python3-lose-cmd-sorted/).

In case there is a "native" Python3 solution I would be happy to learn about it. Comments, improvements, simplifications are welcome.

So, the following code sorts the sets of a list first by the number (here 1 to 5) and second by string in a circular way (here: Ag,Au,Ca,Fe,Ti) such that the last string will be determined by `myRef`.

**Code:**

```
### special numerical and circular alphanumerical sort on a list of sets
from functools import cmp_to_key

# different lists of sets
ag = [(1,'Ag'), (2,'Ag'), (3,'Ag'), (4,'Ag'), (5,'Ag')]
au = [(1,'Au'), (2,'Au')]
ba = []
ca = [(1,'Ca'), (2,'Ca'), (3,'Ca')]
fe = [(1,'Fe'), (2,'Fe')]
ti = [(1,'Ti'), (2,'Ti'), (3,'Ti')]

myList = fe + ti + ag + au + ca + ba     # merge all lists

def mySpecialCircularSort(myList,myRef):
    myList = list(set(myList))                 # remove duplicates
    myListNew = sorted(myList, key=cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: 
        -1 if a[0]<b[0]   else 1 if a[0]>b[0] else 
        -1 if b[1]==myRef else
         1 if a[1]==myRef else
        -1 if a[1]>myRef  and b[1]<myRef else
         1 if a[1]<myRef  and b[1]>myRef else
        -1 if a[1]<b[1]   else
         1 if a[1]>b[1]   else 0))
    print("Circular sort with {} as last: {}".format(myRef,myListNew))

print("Unsorted as is:                {}\n".format(myList))
mySpecialCircularSort(myList,'Ag')
mySpecialCircularSort(myList,'Au')
mySpecialCircularSort(myList,'Ba')   # since Ba-List was empty, the result will be same as 'Au'
mySpecialCircularSort(myList,'Ca')
mySpecialCircularSort(myList,'Fe')
mySpecialCircularSort(myList,'Ti')
```

**Result:**

```
Unsorted as is:                [(1, 'Fe'), (2, 'Fe'), (1, 'Ti'), (2, 'Ti'), (3, 'Ti'), (1, 'Ag'), (2, 'Ag'), (3, 'Ag'), (4, 'Ag'), (5, 'Ag'), (1, 'Au'), (2, 'Au'), (1, 'Ca'), (2, 'Ca'), (3, 'Ca')]

Circular sort with Ag as last: [(1, 'Au'), (1, 'Ca'), (1, 'Fe'), (1, 'Ti'), (1, 'Ag'), (2, 'Au'), (2, 'Ca'), (2, 'Fe'), (2, 'Ti'), (2, 'Ag'), (3, 'Ca'), (3, 'Ti'), (3, 'Ag'), (4, 'Ag'), (5, 'Ag')]
Circular sort with Au as last: [(1, 'Ca'), (1, 'Fe'), (1, 'Ti'), (1, 'Ag'), (1, 'Au'), (2, 'Ca'), (2, 'Fe'), (2, 'Ti'), (2, 'Ag'), (2, 'Au'), (3, 'Ca'), (3, 'Ti'), (3, 'Ag'), (4, 'Ag'), (5, 'Ag')]
Circular sort with Ba as last: [(1, 'Ca'), (1, 'Fe'), (1, 'Ti'), (1, 'Ag'), (1, 'Au'), (2, 'Ca'), (2, 'Fe'), (2, 'Ti'), (2, 'Ag'), (2, 'Au'), (3, 'Ca'), (3, 'Ti'), (3, 'Ag'), (4, 'Ag'), (5, 'Ag')]
Circular sort with Ca as last: [(1, 'Fe'), (1, 'Ti'), (1, 'Ag'), (1, 'Au'), (1, 'Ca'), (2, 'Fe'), (2, 'Ti'), (2, 'Ag'), (2, 'Au'), (2, 'Ca'), (3, 'Ti'), (3, 'Ag'), (3, 'Ca'), (4, 'Ag'), (5, 'Ag')]
Circular sort with Fe as last: [(1, 'Ti'), (1, 'Ag'), (1, 'Au'), (1, 'Ca'), (1, 'Fe'), (2, 'Ti'), (2, 'Ag'), (2, 'Au'), (2, 'Ca'), (2, 'Fe'), (3, 'Ti'), (3, 'Ag'), (3, 'Ca'), (4, 'Ag'), (5, 'Ag')]
Circular sort with Ti as last: [(1, 'Ag'), (1, 'Au'), (1, 'Ca'), (1, 'Fe'), (1, 'Ti'), (2, 'Ag'), (2, 'Au'), (2, 'Ca'), (2, 'Fe'), (2, 'Ti'), (3, 'Ag'), (3, 'Ca'), (3, 'Ti'), (4, 'Ag'), (5, 'Ag')]
```

Comment: ...obsolete... @georg's solution is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

With a custom sort key function:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

order = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(ascii_uppercase)}

def circular_sort(lst, last):
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], order[x[1]] + 26*(x[1]<=last)))

>>> circular_sort(a+b+c+d, 'B')
[(1, 'D'), (2, 'D'), (3, 'D'), (4, 'D'), (1, 'A'), (2, 'A'), (3, 'A'), (4, 'A'), (5, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'B')]
```

This simply adds 26 to any letter's index that is less or equal to the specified last letter.

Comment: thank for your suggestion. I edited the question and clarified. The numbers should have the higher sort priority. So, first all `1`'s then `2`s etc. and then D,A,B, as second priority. i.e. `1D, 1A, 1B, 2D, 2A, 2B, 3D, 3A, 3B, 4D, 4A, 5A`

Comment: Just turn the key tuple around then. Edited the answer..

Comment: well, still not the desired order... as I wrote it should be: `1D, 1A, 1B, 2D, 2A, 2B, 3D, 3A, 3B, 4D, 4A, 5A`, but I guess the custom sort function is the key. I need to look it up how this works.

Comment: after some further search, I guess `lambda` and `cmp(x,y)` would have done the job, but it doesn't exist in Python3 anymore. (See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch02s05.html ) So, then probably maybe something with `operator.itemgetter()` or `operator.methodcaller()` from which I still don't have a clue how to use...

Answer (score 0):

I see a pattern in the sample data:

```
a = [(1,'A'), (2,'A'), (3,'A'), (4,'A'), (5,'A')]
b = [(1,'B'), (2,'B'), (3,'B')]
c = []
d = [(1,'D'), (2,'D'), (3,'D'), (4,'D')]
```

Maybe the pattern is misleading me, while the real data doesn't have the same pattern.
**In this case, just ignore my answer.**

Otherwise, given the OP's answer to my comment:

> starting point is several separate lists

I propose this solution:

- build a nested list with the source lists;
- rotate the list `n` times depending on the starting point;
- transpose;
- flatten;

Here is an example of implementation, defining some helpers:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def rotate(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]

def transpose(l):
    return [list(filter(None,i)) for i in zip_longest(*tmp)]

def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

Then, for example rotate three times to start with `D`:

```
tmp = [a, b, c, d]
tmp = rotate(tmp, 3)
tmp = transpose(tmp)
tmp = flatten(tmp)
tmp
#=> [(1, 'D'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'D'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'D'), (3, 'A'), (3, 'B'), (4, 'D'), (4, 'A'), (5, 'A')]
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. If I take the data from my answer, as far as I can tell your suggestion will give the desired result as well. Although I have to specify a number for shift/rotate instead of the string `D`. But this could also be solved. For clarity and flexibility I will go for Georg's solution.